# Cakephp `` escaping my Calculating Field names

Tags: sql, cakephp

This used to work:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
  'fields' => 'Model.field/100 as name')
```

but I now get a SQL error because the fields are encapsulated with field inverted commas:

```
SELECT `Model.field/100 as name` FROM models AS Model ..
```

which *should* be

```
SELECT Model.field/100 as name FROM models AS Model ..
```

I recently installed a newer version of Cakephp 1.3.6 to 1.3.13 but the manuals don't mention any changes.

This is a very annoying and unncessary problem, does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Ok, found a clue, but still don't know why:

Cakephp wants the expression to be in parentheses, so 
  
        'fields' => array('Model.field/100 as name')  

doesn't work, but 

        'fields' => array('(Model.field/100) as name')  

does. And this all of a sudden...

Comment: i was going to write the same thing XD to put them in parenthesis and also use as in capital letters AS some sql commands cake only recognize them if you put them capitalized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a clue, but still don't know why:

Cakephp wants the expression to be in parentheses, so

```
    'fields' => array('Model.field/100 as name')
```

doesn't work, but

```
    'fields' => array('(Model.field/100) as name')
```

does.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use virtualFields for this. they can contain such expressions